# Why does shifting by full width behave differently for constant versus variable?

Tags: c, bit-shift

If I use `3 << 32`, I get the correct result.
If I find the size using `sizeof(int)`, multiply by 8, store the result in a variable, and then use `3 << variable`, I get a different result. What am I missing here?

```
void func()
{
    unsigned int sz = sizeof(number) * 8;
    unsigned int k = 0;
    printf("Value of sz is %u \r\n",sz);
    k = (k | (0x3) << sz);
    printf("Value of 2_1_MSB is %d \r\n",(3 << 32));
     printf("Value of k is %u \r\n",k);
}
```

Comment: Your title asks about the difference between two programs, but you show only part of one. You do not include an [mcve], so others cannot compile your code to attempt to reproduce the behavior. You do not say what results you observe nor which result you perceive to be the correct one.

Comment: Undefined Behaviour is *undefined*; your program isn't required to give any particular output (or even any output at all).

Comment: Why did you multiply by 8?  Did you actually mean `CHAR_BIT` there?

Answer (score 5):

The C standard defines shift behavior only for shifts less than the width of the type being shifted (C 2018 6.5.7 3). Shifting a 32-bit `int` by 32 bits is not defined by the standard.

Differences between `3 << 32` and `(0x3) << sz` may arise due to the compiler evaluating the former at compile time (perhaps using an operation that shifts all bits out, resulting in zero) and the latter at execution time (perhaps using an instruction that uses only the low five bits of the shift amount, resulting in no shift). Such behaviors may not be relied upon; they may change with optimization, change of target or other compiler configuration, change of compiler version, and so on.

Answer (score 5):

On all modern PC-type platforms, `int` has only 32 bits. Shifting by more than that is undefined. And remember that bit numbers for shifting are zero-based, so for a 32-bit type (like `int`) then the valid bit range is `0` to `31` (inclusive).

Now for the difference between `3 << 32` and `3 << sz`: In the first case the compiler can know that it's shifting more than 32 bits, so it can infer that it will be a 64-bit operation (using `long long`). In the second case the compiler doesn't know the value of `sz` because it's a plain variable and not a compile-time constant. Therefore it has to assume that it's a plain `int` shift and that the value of `sz` is in range.

Comment: "In the first case the compiler can know that it's shifting more than 32 bits, so it can infer that it will be a 64-bit operation (using long long)." Eh? Are you trying to describe some non-standard extension here? Because shifting too many bits is as you say, undefined.

Comment: I agree, it is unlikely the compiler would choose to implement an `int` shift using `long long` based on the shift amount. I can think of four likely prospects: The compiler evaluates `3 << 32` using some simple code that shifts and that happens to shift bits out, causing wrapping. The compiler evaluates `3 << 32` (and arithmetic expressions generally) using its internal maximum-width integer, so the result is the bits are shifted out of the low 32 positions. The compiler recognizes `3 << 32` is undefined and exposes it to optimization, which transforms it to zero for whatever reasons.